# How to insert the ID of a combobox to a Mysql table

Tags: mysql, combobox, pyqt5

Does anyone know how to retrieve the ID of the selected combobox. I want to enter the ID of the selected product to a MYSQL table. But I don't want that ID to appear in the combobox.

```py
def combi(self):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='rincon', db='texpal')
    cur = connection.cursor()   
    sql = "SELECT cod,name FROM chemical"
    data = cur.execute(sql)
    result = cur.fetchall()

    for i,row in result:
        self.comboBox.addItem(str(row[0]) + row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding an item to a combo box you can use the `userData` parameter to add e extra data, e.g.

```
def combi(self):
    ...

    for i,row in result:
        self.comboBox.addItem(str(row[0]), userData=row[1])
```

This data can later be retrieved via `QComboBox.itemData()`:

```
def get_item(self, index):
    item_text = self.comboBox.itemText(index)
    item_id = self.comboBox.itemData(index)
    print(f'item: {item_text}, id: {item_id}')
```